# Highchart data labels appear in middle if xAxis ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Please consider this code:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
        },
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},
```

[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/1h0f4za8/)

When xAxis category is numeric (years) data labels align with xAxis tick, but when I change categories and set the to some string, data labels align in the middle of xAxis ticks.

```
categories:["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh"]
```

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/7qkfvbzr/)

How I can align values on exact top of the xAxis ticks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement)) setting to correct this. API-description:

> For categorized axes only. If `on` the tick mark is placed in the center of the category, if `between` the tick mark is placed between categories. The default is `between` if the `tickInterval` is 1, else `on`.

For example:

```
xAxis: {
    categories:["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh"],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/7qkfvbzr/2/) of it in use.